# Should use D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC or D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT when creating a constant buffer for model-view-projection transform?

Tags: c++, directx

From all DirectX 11 template projects provided by Visual Studio I have seen, the sample codes use "D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT" usage flag when creating constant buffer for model-view-projection transform matrices.
However, from the msdn guildline ([Choosing a Resource (Direct3D 10)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205129(v=vs.85).aspx)), it clearly says that if the buffer needs to be updated on per-frame base (which is the case of updating the transform matrices for each frame), then we should use D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC for better CPU access and thus better performance.
Could anyone suggest me whether the template project does not care about performance or I have wrong understanding about the guideline?

Comment: The reason I said those buffers are created with "D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT" is they are updated by "UpdateSubresource()", otherwise, for dynamic buffer, should use "Map()/UnMap()" to update.

Comment: Did you see this?
https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/673486-difference-between-d3d11-usage-default-and-d3d11-usage-dynamic/
Last comment looks legit

Comment: Thanks matt for your info, it is very helpful.